# ES6 modules are throwing "super expression must either be null or a function" error

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am very new to webpack and modules, so be patient when I ask this.

I keep getting a "Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined" error when using webpack modules.

**library**

I have one webpack project that generates a `library.js` from a single file containing two classes:

```
export class Component {
    update() {
        alert("component");
    }   
} 

export class Template {
    update() {
        alert("template update");
    }   
}
```

**project**

I thought I could copy `library.js` into the project folder and import them like this:

```
import {Template, Component} from "./library.js"
```

But as I said earlier, I'm getting that error and obviously doing something pretty wrong.

Comment: Also tried 'library' without '.js'

Comment: Is that the only code in your project? Are you sure you don't have circular references anywhere?

Comment: Yes. No circular references. Its actually two projects. One is library and one is the app.

Comment: OK, if those are your complete files then please tell me from which line the error message stems, as your code doesn't even have a super expression (`class extends …`).

Comment: I figured out that I needed to add library and libraryTarget to webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I needed to add library and libraryTarget to webpack.config.js